# VS Wizard Template - Change Project solution and directory

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I'm writing a Visual Studio Wizard Template using c# on visual studio 2012.

I followed the MSDN steps:
I created a VS template, then I created a Class Library project with a class which implements the IWizard interface, I configured the .vstemplate file and etc...

Now, my target is to write in the `RunStarted` function code, which does the following:

On the project creation, it copies another existing solution directory from another location to the new project selected location, and then, instead of creating the new project in a new solution, the new project will be added to the copied solution, in a specific "apps" folder, and no new solution will be created.

In the `RunStarted` method I wrote a simple `CopyDirectory` code which copies the wanted solution to the `$SolutionDirectory$` which I extracted from the `ReplacementsDictionary` parameter. But now, I don't success to continue and change the new project configuration though it will be generated as a project of the copied solution.

Do you have any idea about this issue?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. If you have the [DTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) \ [Solution2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte80.solution2.aspx) object of the solution, you can use the [AddFromFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4y34x89h.aspx) method  or directly add the project from the template by using [AddFromTemplate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/behck2xd.aspx) method.

   The current `DTE` object can be obtained by the `GetService()` method:

   // Get an instance of the currently running Visual Studio IDE

   DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
2. If you can't get the solution as DTE object, you can edit the `.sln file` by using `XML` editing (look in existing .sln file how the projects added).

Comment: Hi, I got into a problem: I used your solution on VS 2012 and everything worked well, but now I have to get it working also on VS 2010. I read in the MSDN that Project Template is not available in C++ 2010, and that I can use only the .vsz templates, which behave totally different: it uses JavaScript code. in 2012 I had a .vstemplate template, and a classLibrary.dll which implements IWizard. Do you know what can I do in order to have the closest solution on 2010?

Comment: Why do you not use `.vsz template` for both- 2010 and 2012 templates? It can prevent double code. The only change between .vsz template of 2010 to the one of 2012 is in the line `Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.11.0`
in VS2012 compared to `Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.10.0` in VS2010.

Comment: Because I wanted to write the code behind the template in c# using DTE, and the code behind the .vsz template is in Java Script.